# Documents in SharePoint Library are not getting open in MS office 365 Client - SHAREPOINT ADMIN

Tags: central-administration, server-farm, sharepoint-administration, sharepoint-admin-center

We have setup the SharePoint Server with 1 App Server, 1 Web Front Server and 1 DB Server. This is for production setup. All the ports were closed in these production servers. Only we have opened the required ports.

Now, we are storing Office documents like Work and Excel in the document library.

User are having MS Office(Office 365) version installed in their machines.

Now user is trying to access the Office document, Users are getting error like "Cannot download the information you requested" on opening in office document in MS office client.

Click on document in SharePoint --> It is asking whether to open in Client office(Word, Excel) --> User click open work or excel --> Excel or Work opening with immediately error pop up saying "Cannot download the information you requested".

Inside the server, when we are accessing this documents, it is opening as expected.

CAN YOU GUYS PLEASE HELP, DO WE NEED TO OPEN ANY SPECIFIC PORTS TO ACCESS SHAREPOINT DOCUMENT FROM OFFICE CLIENT ?

PLEASE HELP.

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR YOUR HELP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone lands this page by having problem in connecting with OFFICE CLIENT with documents present in DOCUMENT LIBRARY at SHAREPOINT...

```
**Please use the fiddler to track the processes happening on the OFFICE CLIENT on opening the document. This will give completely the information about the various call getting called from office client.**
```

In my case HTTP OPTIONS call was made by Office client and in the SERVER this call had blocked due to security issues and hence not able to connect.

Once Un-block HTTP OPTIONS method in the server, I was able to communicate with SHAREPOINT documents from office.